# Split string and keep separator as new result item

Tags: c#, string

Having string like `11+2-33` I need to split it into `11,+,2,-,33`

this produce me 11+,2-,33
 `Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[+,-])")`

so I need to apply it again on each result item, is there better way ?

Comment: Its also unclear if 11,+,2,+,33 is a new string, or an array of items [11],[+],[2],[+],[33]?

Comment: The output in your question `11+,2-,33` is different from what you need `11,+,2,-,33`, also "is there better way ?" is implying that you have a working solution, but I guess that is not the case

Comment: yes but if apply Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[+,-])") on each element of 11+,2-,33 then I should have 11,+,2,-,33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both look-behind and look-ahead, just as you've said:

```
var matches = Regex.Split("11+2-33", "(?<=[+-])|(?=[+-])");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", matches));
```

`11,+,2,-,33`

Comment: Your expression matches the operators `+`, `-` and `,`. I think that you mean `(?<=[+-])|(?=[+-])`.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa, the expression is using the OP pattern, including look-ahead on top of the look-behind. I'm not sure if OP was using `[+,-]` on purpose or not, but apparently - you are right - he indeed was checking for `+`, `,`, and `-`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression that matches either a number or an operator. Example:

```
string expression = "11+2-33";

string[] parts =
  Regex.Matches(expression, @"\d+|[+-]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

foreach (string s in parts) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
11
+
2
-
33
```

Comment: what does Cast<Match>() do ?

Comment: @kosnkov: It convert the `MatchCollection` object that is returned from the `Matches` collection into an `IEnumerable<Match>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regex expert, so there may be a clever way to do it with a regex, matches, etc., but how *I* would do it is add delimiters:

```
string s = "11+2-33";
s = s.Replace("+","|+|");
s = s.Replace("-","|-|");

string[] parts = s.Split('|');
```

You can refactor from there but that's the general idea.

Comment: This makes me think that there should be a `StringSplitOptions.RetainDelimeters` option